# Trans inside form.placeholder Symfony 4

Tags: symfony, symfony4

I'm translating my application based on a value defined in the database( not locale ).

This is the part of the form:

```
$builder
        ->add('email', EmailType::class, array( 'required' => 'required', 'attr' => array( 'class' => 'form-control','placeholder' => 'Email')))
        ->add('username', TextType::class, array( 'required' => 'required', 'attr' => array( 'class' => 'form-control', 'autofocus' => 'autofocus','placeholder' => 'Username')))
        ->add('plainPassword', RepeatedType::class, array(
            'type' => PasswordType::class,
            'first_options'  => array('label' => 'Password', 'attr' => array( 'class' => 'form-control repeat', 'placeholder' => 'Password')),
            'second_options' => array('label' => 'Repeat Password', 'attr' => array( 'class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Repeat password')),
        ))
        ->add('termsAccepted', CheckboxType::class, array(
            'mapped' => false,
            'constraints' => new IsTrue(),
            'attr' => array('class' => 'pull-left')
    ))
    ;
```

This part of my twig template

```
<h1 class="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal form-header">{% trans into lang %}Register{% endtrans %}</h1>
{{ form_start(form, { 'attr': {'class': 'form-signin'} }) }}
{{ form_row(form.username, {'label':false}) }}
{{ form_row(form.email, {'label':false}) }}
{{ form_row(form.plainPassword.first, {'label':false}) }}
{{ form_row(form.plainPassword.second, {'label':false}) }}
{{ form_row(form.termsAccepted, {'label':false}) }}
<p class="terms">Check here to indicate that you read and agree the  <a href="{{ path('privacy_policy') }}">Privacy Policy.</a></p>
<button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Register</button>
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

Based on:
{% trans into lang %}text to translate{% endtrans %}

If i try to trans the entire field, make an exception with "trans only can proceed simply text".

There's any trick to passthrough the placeholder directly to my twig template?.

Answer (score 0):

For dynamic content, you should use trans filter instead.

```
{{ message|trans(arguments = [], domain = null, locale = null) }}
```

Should be something like

```
{{ textToTranslate | trans([], null, lang) }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Good practice is to use translation keys.
At Twig it looks like:

```
{{ 'some_bundle.special_controller.its_view.your_trans_key'|trans }}
```

Than in messages.en.yml:

```
some_bundle:
  special_controller:
    its_view:
      your_trans_key: 'This is translation key!'
      other_key: 'And this is another translation key!'
  second_controller:
    and_its_view:
      some_key: 'The Key'
```

Of. You can make your keys structure the way You want.

Edit: it should work if You put this long key at Form placeholder:

```
...'placeholder' => 'some_bundle.some_form.plain_password.password')),
...'placeholder' => 'some_bundle.some_form.plain_password.repeat_password')),
```

Default Symfony view should translate this key. Check it out.